# Underline text with jTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextpane

Hello everyone I have a panel where I use a JTextPane and I want to alternate with text and underline text, but I don't know why I can't underline the part of the text that I want to underline.
here is my code where I only wan to underline the text:"Underline":

```
public class TestMLD extends JPanel{
    
    private MLD mld;
    
    TestMLD() throws BadLocationException{
        init();
    }
    
    private void init() throws BadLocationException {
        

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setOpaque(false);
        
          SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
          StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
          textPane.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);
          Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 18);
          textPane.setFont(font);
          StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
          Style style = textPane.addStyle("", null);
          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Some text ", style);
          
          

          StyleConstants.setUnderline(attributeSet, true);
          /**THE PART I WANT TO UNDERLINE **/
          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Underline ", style);
          StyleConstants.setUnderline(attributeSet, false);
          
          
          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Some text\n", style);
          JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
          textPane.setEditable(false);
          add(textPane);
         
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.getContentPane().add(new TestMLD());

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setSize(400, 400);
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }



}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen, since you commented out the code with the underline attribute. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We can't copy/paste/compile/test the posted code.

Comment: I change the posted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      StyleConstants.setUnderline(attributeSet, true);
```

You are setting the "underline" attribute for the "attributeSet".

```
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Underline ", style);
```

Why are you trying to use a "style". Your "style" variable has not attributes.

Use the "attributeSet" since it contains your attributes:

```
      //doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Underline ", style);
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Underline ", attributeSet);
```

Also, why are you trying to set an "Italic" attribute:

```
      StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
      textPane.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);
      Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 18);
```

You are using an "Italic" Font.

Get rid of:

```
      //StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
      //textPane.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);
```